# Looking for word/expression/idiom that describes "difficult to describe driving directions"

Tags: vocabulary, expressions

On lives in a part of town which has new roads most cab drivers don't know. In effect, one needs to direct the driver to the part of town, instead of just saying "take me to street X that intersects w/ street Y"

Question: I want say that "I am stuck to hard-to-describe directions, while you're NOT."

My thinking is, "while  I am stuck to less amenable directions"

Comment: It makes a big difference whether what you're trying to describe relates to *the area being new, so the driver may not know it well* (in which case **unfamiliar** would do), or to the *the complexity of the actual route* (in which case **tortuous, complicated**, or **labrynthine** would do). But avoid that last unless your cabbie seems reasonably well-educated.

Comment: (a) Complicated seems a good choice (b) I'm actually addressing  the friend, who, by contrast, has an easier time describing directions. So instead of belaboring on directions, he can concentrate on picking up girls. Hence I want to cleverly respond to his comments in regard to latter: "Me for the next 1-3 years:  “hey, you know you can see the Big building from my apartment!  You know, with the nice clear/foggy/rainy weather it probably looks really cool tonight.  Want to see"........... while  me [Fedor]has to work on relating complex directions

Comment: Well, I see you're from New York, where I'm sure all the cabs must have satnav. Just give the cabbie your postcode when you get in. Then you can concentrate on chatting up your (prospective?) girl on the back seat until you hear that synthesised voice saying "**You have reached your destination**" :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers  you're missing the point. Perhaps I wasnt clear with you. the words I am looking for are NOT for, but for my friend...

Comment: Not your fault, I realise, but your question is quite difficult to understand. Still, you can always use your friend's postcode (sorry - **ZIP** code in NY). And maybe chat up *his* girlfriend while the two of you are in a cab going to visit him!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "I'm a place that practically needs GPS (Global Positioning System) to
>   locate, while you're not".

I've been in those places before. The first thing I do is get a GPS location with a satellite phone and store that information in my mobile phone so that in case of an emergency,  I can send out my GPS coordinates.

The word [convoluted](http://www.wordnik.com/words/convoluted) comes to mind though:

> highly complex or intricate and occasionally devious: *I'm stuck here
>   because of **convoluted** directions, while you're not!*